# NXT 1.0 software issue

Tags: nxt, software

I am an educator with 33 Mindstorm NXT 1.0 computers. We are a Mac school and are running El Capitan (OS 10.11). Two questions...

1. Is it possible to download the 1.0 software to our Macs? Has there been any update/upgrade to the 1.0 software?
2. I'm assuming I can't use 2.0 software with the 1.0 units correct?

Comment: Looks like http://www.onemindstorm.com/nxt-software-support/ has a solution for installing on a previous mac version of OS 10.  The instructions may work.  They also have links to download the software.  I don't own a mac to test that it does work.  I can't describe this as an answer without knowing it works.  If you get it to work, please add the steps you used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about compatibility of different versions of NXT-G with different versions of macOS. However, regarding your second question:

The only difference between the 1.0, 2.0, and Education NXT kits is the parts and sensors that come in the kit. There is only one hardware revision of NXT brick, and any version of NXT-G will work with any NXT brick. Thus, if you found a version of NXT-G other than 1.0 that will run on El Capitan, you could use it program your NXT bricks.